# how to connect and subscribe from cumulocity to MQTT broker

Tags: mqtt, cumulocity

I have an  external broker us Apache Active MQ-MQTT.

I have a cumulocity IoT platform on the cloud.

I don’t  understand how I can connect and subscribe  my cumulocity application to  broker MQTT.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, as it stands there is not enough information in your question for anybody to be able to help. Please read the guide on asking good questions https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in feature that would enable you to connect Cumulocity to an external MQTT broker. You could however create your own microservice that does this for you.

Comment: Thanks for you information. 
If I deploy a microservice , How can I deploy the registration of device feature . Can I use the cumulocity gui  device management/register devices ( if yes how ) , or I must develop a specify gui  into the microservice.

Comment: Device registration is a standard feature of Cumulocity. I don't understand what your microservice has to do with it. As mentioned in the comment on your original post I would need a bit more explanation to understand your goal.